# Migrating negative boost to elasticsearch v7

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-7

Elastic search [disallows negative boost](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/33309) values with v7. Is there a way to reproduce the same behaviour in the new version v7 as it worked in v6 or lower?

I.e. if I had a `should` query with various `multi_match` queries (or other) and one or more of them previously had a negative `boost`, it ment in v6, that when the score of the `bool` query was summed, it reduced the overall score, of the `should` query.

The docs and [migration notes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_negative_boosts_are_not_allowed) states, that a score between 0 and 1 should be used instead. But as the `should` query will always be summed (not multiplied) it will not have the same effect.

**Example**:
*(factors = boost values)*

`(score1 * 1.5)+ (score2 * 2) + (score3 * - 2.3) + (score4 * -1)`

How could I get the same result in ES7?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [boosting query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/query-dsl-boosting-query.html) to demote certain documents without excluding them from the search results. I hope this will help you. you can refer [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/elasticsearch-reducing-relevance-some-documents-boosting-fl%C3%A1vio-knob?articleId=6656235513688702976) article for practicle example.

Comment: This is not what I want, as the docs say this boosting query works as follows: 
> Take the original relevance score from the positive query. Then multiply the score by the negative_boost value.`
How could I solve the describe problem with this method? Maybe partially, but what if previously I had something like this: (score*1.5)+ (score*2) + (score3*-2.3) + (score4 * -1) how could I get the same result?

Comment: As i know this is only way for negative boosting in 7.x version of ES. can you try with your data set and check how relevancy is changing.

Comment: I dont think that there is a way to get the same behaviour. Maybe for one negative score, but not for several which should have a different impact on the overall relevance, because only one negative_boost value can be defined if the whole negative query matches. I could not find any other way either, so I came up with the question in the first place. Thanks for your effort.